# Cast System.Data.Linq.Table<T> to custom class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I do a request on my sql table using `Linq to SQL`. I get a instance of `System.Data.Linq.Table<Table>`

I have also a class with some properties which corresponds to the properties of my table (The properties have the same name as the properties of my instance of `System.Data.Linq.Table<Table>`)

How to cast the `System.Data.Linq.Table<Table>` to a instance of my custom class ?

Without do `Select(x => new CustomClass() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name ....})` and without (if possible) using `Reflexion` (it's so slow)

Comment: Have a look at [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Comment: What is the difference her with `Linq To Sql` ? I get a `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Table>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your objects
You can check the getting started page here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Basically you'll setup a mapping between your `Table` and `CustomClass` classes

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Table, CustomClass>());
```

Then you can map a `Table` instance to a `CustomClass`one

```
CustomClass myCustomClass= Mapper.Map<CustomClass>(table);
```

Comment: Yes but is there a native method ?

Comment: Though it is a good suggestion one liner link answer are without much help. Please provide a short example relevant to the question of how that can be in use

Comment: @user6852886 what do you mean native? If you don't want to use an external package maybe you can use an implicit cast operator between your classes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: simple guide to use automapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use a external librairy